# unresolved problems with C++ EDITTEXT and DIRECTSHOW PAUSE()

Tags: c++, directshow, atl, graphedit

i have a simple winform that writes to an EDITTEXT , as the program goes on the printing process executing perfectly . but once i click the STOP BUTTON which firstly calls the PAUSE()
function my program gets stuck inside the

```
SetWindowText(m_hWatermarksEditBox, &m_watermarkLog[0]);
```

all values are initialized and proper data gets in.

my guess is that i have to declare a METHOD WORKER , like in C#.NET but i dont know how.

```
STDMETHODIMP CNaveFilter::Pause()
        {
            ATLTRACE(L"(%0.5d)CNaveFilter::Pause() (this:0x%.8x)\r\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), (DWORD)this);
            HRESULT hr = S_OK;
            CAutoLock __lock(&m_cs);
            hr = CBaseFilter::Pause();
            return hr;
        }

        STDMETHODIMP CNaveFilter::Stop()
        {
            ATLTRACE(L"(%0.5d)CNaveFilter::Stop() (this:0x%.8x)\r\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), (DWORD)this);
            HRESULT hr = S_OK;
            CAutoLock __lock(&m_cs);

            hr = CBaseFilter::Stop();
            ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
            return hr;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where you are doing `SetWindowText` but as you have the custom filter the most likely problem is that with this call you block your streaming/worker thread execution and the involved threads lock dead.

`SetWindowText` is only safe to be called from your UI thread (well, technically not only it, but definitely not a streaming thread). So if you want to update the control text or send any message to it, you have to do it in a different way, so that your caller thread could keep running.

Typically, you would store some relevant information in member variable (don't forget critical section lock) then `PostMessage`, receive the message on your window/control and handle it there in the right thread, calling `SetWindowText` there.

See [controlling frame/rate and exposure time through sampleCB](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/c6b46cf7-bf7f-4624-aa73-321694b83016). It covers a bit different topic, but useful in terms of sending/posting messages in a DirectShow filter.